# Group elements by position

Tags: jquery, position

A `#gal` container is loaded with lots of images (~60), all with defined CSS height (100px) and margin 5px;

Now, logically, the images widths may vary and when all images are visible, we cannot count the same number of images-per-'line' as they are all floated down if not room available to fit the `#gal` width:

```
| ___ __ _____ _ | <--- the #gal with images inside
| __ ______      |
| ______ _ __ __ |
| __ ______      |
| _______ ____ _ |
```

How to group all images in the 'first' line (second... third...) by `wrap()`ing them into a DIV ?

So here is a first idea: 
 - after the page is loaded and images are positioned - we could group all the images by its `.position().top`:

```
5  5  5  5
120 120
245 245 245 245 
380 380
525 525 525
```

### [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ECTvp/)

Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're actually asking us.

Comment: Do you wan't to group all the images so that they all fill out one line together? like you have 2 images of 200 pixels and 2 of 600 so instead of making line1: 200+200, line2: 600 and line3: 600 you want to make line1: 200+600 and line2: 200+600 ?

Comment: No, after images are loaded we can visually group them into 'lines' Ex: Images in the first 'line', images in second 'line' images in 'third' line..... and so on. How to wrap each line of images into a DIV? I know that a great help could be that - all images in Ex 'second' line shares the same `position().top` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a function that returns the `".wrapper"` Element using [jQuery's Object Element creator](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements).
- Inside a **single loop** check for the `.next()` element position is greater than the current one's.
  If true, pass to the `$wrap()` function a set of elements in the range of *last-known-index* to *current index + 1* **by using `.slice()`.**
- Insert the  generated wrappers Elements into and array, and once the work is done append that array to the `#gal` parent.

```js
const wrapGalImg = () => {

  const $el = $('#gal img'),
    $wrap = ($ch) => $('<div>', {'class':'wrapper', append:$ch}),
    wraps = []; // Array of wrapper elements with children
  let i = 0;

  $el.each((ei, ele) => {
    const $next = $(ele).next();
    if($next[0] && $next.position().top == $(ele).position().top) return;
    wraps.push($wrap($el.slice(i, ei+1)));
    i = ei+1;
  });
  
  $('#gal').append( wraps ); // Append all wrappers. Once.

}

$(window).on('load', wrapGalImg);
```

```css
*{margin: 0;}

#gal img {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 60px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #f00;
  margin: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="gal">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x120/000/fff?text=FIRST">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/175x104/f0f/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/a3d/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/278x125/cf5/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/199x120/e46/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/207x480/361/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x107/081/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x40/cc3/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/700x500/233/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x120/a26/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/301x177/f1d/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/164x239/d34/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/34e/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/175x120/72a/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/210x110/112/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/278x225/644/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x120/dc3/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/90x104/b30/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x60/bb3/fff">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/140x125/aa3/fff?text=LAST">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

---

So, no need for multiple loops, cloning or removing elements.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var div = $('<div />'); // The current working div
var pos = $('#gal img').position().top; // The position of the first image

$('#gal img').each(function(){
    // If the next image has a different position from the one before it
    // then add the working div to #gal and create a new working div.
    if (pos != $(this).position().top) {
        $('#gal').append(div);
        div = $('<div />');  
    }

    // Append a cloned copy of the image to the working div.
    // This is important: we don't want to move the image
    // because it will reflow the other images and mess up
    // the rows.
    div.append($(this).clone());

    // Set the new position
    pos = $(this).position().top;
});

// Now remove all of the old images
$('#gal > img').remove();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PuqZe/1/

Comment: Why you defined two times div = $('<div />') ??

Comment: The first time starts with an empty div. Then once a row of images is added to it, I append the div to #gal. Then I have it again to reset the div back to an empty div for the next row.

Comment: I'm pretty sure creating clones won't do you any good performance wise.

Comment: How so? It's a clone of a single element.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var groups = {};

$('#gal img').each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position().top;
    if(typeof groups[pos] == 'undefined')
    {
        groups[pos] = [];
    }
    groups[pos].push(this);
});

$.each(groups, function (pos, elements) {
    $('#gal').append('<div id="wrapper_'+pos+'" class="wrapper"></div>');
    var wrapper = $('#gal #wrapper_'+pos);
    $.each(elements, function () {
        wrapper.append(this);
    });
});
```

It will wrap all the images with the same position top in a wrapper div.

Comment: This almost does it, but you need two loops because the wrapping of the first element can affect the position of the others in that row, causing them not to get wrapped with the first element the way they should.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/kr57a/2/

```
var gal = $('#gal');

gal.children('img').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el[0].Pos = el.position().top;
})
.each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var rowWrapper = gal.children('.group' + el[0].Pos);
    if(rowWrapper.length === 0){
        el.wrap('<div class="wrapper group' + el[0].Pos + '"></div>');
    }else{
        el.appendTo(rowWrapper);
    }
});
```

We loop through the images twice. The first time gets their position, storing it as a property on the HTML element object (el[0]). The second loop does the wrapping. The reason we need two loops is because the wrapping can affect the position of the other unwrapped elements in the same row, causing them not to get wrapped with the first element in that row.